# AppleScript: How to return a boolean from an event called inside an if() statement

Tags: applescript

Hi—Applescript nub here.

I'm not actually trying to run the script below, per se, but I'm trying to find an AppleScript language construct that will achieve this effect (which works fine in languages I'm familiar with, haha):

```
set adoc to choose file
tell application "Finder"
    tell application "TextEdit"
        open adoc
    end tell
    tell application process "Textedit" of application "System Events"
        if (click menu item "Print…" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "TextEdit" of application "System Events") then
            display dialog "It worked boss!"
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

Basically I'm GUI scripting an old application and need to know at every step of the way if an event has happened. I know I can just infer the success of the event by asking if the Print window exists, for example, but for reasons I won't get into I don't wish to infer the event from it's expected consequences, I want to know if it happened. Is there a way to do this in AppleScript? Thanks!

---

Interestingly enough, for my foolishly esoteric purposes the combination of both of the answers provided got me through the hoops of scripting some really old apps. In some cases, one of two possible windows with similar buttons could be present, wherein the {x,y} solution—for my purposes, the more effective in several cases—doesn't work because I can still correctly click the wrong button, wherein the application of the try...on error strategy (which I actually feel kind of foolishness not to have considered), which doesn't give me the same precision because some of UI elements I'm working with are bizarre and don't behave as expected (or have the properties expected), at least overcomes that problem. Thanks to everyone for saving me from this nightmare!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another approach. For actions and clicks it will return the object when successful or another object. Match these objects to be certain that no other object than the target has received the action.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        if (count of windows) < 1 then return --there are no windows, no reason to continue
        tell window 1
            tell checkbox 1 of group 1
                if (click it) is not it then
                    --click has failed; stop 
                    return
                end if
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

--EDIT: added some example code for adayzdone to show him how it can work with printing

```
tell application "Safari" to activate --comment//uncomment this line
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        set theTarget to menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
        set {xPos, yPos} to position of theTarget
        if (click at {xPos, yPos}) is not theTarget then
            return false
        end if
        set theTarget to last menu item of menu 1 of menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
        set {xPos, yPos} to position of theTarget
        if (click at {xPos, yPos}) is not theTarget then
            return false
        end if
        return true
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: What do you mean ayazdone? print from the main menu? Excactly the same was as above. For static ui elements I prefer to use click at {x, y} instead of the click object command to be sure the right object is clicked.

Comment: I don't understand the workflow. The user clicks first and then script is run? Script run in loop? Script run and then user clicks?

Comment: Nope... the script clicks 'as an user'. So we need to popup the menu first – we click at a location and check the results. The result of this click is the UI element where it is actually clicked or missing value. If the application is not active the menu isn't displayed. So it stops. The reason I didn't use this method in the first example is because the first example isn't an static UI element loaded from a nib file but is code generated, which means that it is only available when the menu is shown while menu bar item 3 always exists, displayed or not.

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, AppleScript has no notion of *truthy* and *falsy* – the only values evaluating to `true` or `false` are booleans proper (either values or expressions). Consistent with that, neither 0, nor an empty string, nor `missing value` can be coerced to `false`.

If you want to test the success of your GUI scripting operation, you will either have to compare the returned value to the one expected, for instance by comparing the class of the return value with that of the targeted object in the *UI element* class hierarchy, i.e.

```
if class of (click menu item "Print…" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of process "TextEdit" of application "System Events") is menu item then
    display dialog "It worked, Boss"
end if
```

or leverage OSA’s heavy usage of exceptions by wrapping your code in a `try … on error` block, i.e.

```
try
    click menu item "Print…" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of process "TextEdit" of application "System Events"
    display dialog "It worked, Boss"
on error errorMessage
    log errorMessage
end try
```

I’ll refrain from commenting on your example code, which includes several errors which will stop it from working as expected, as you said you are not actually trying to run it…